# Sorting an observableArray for one of the templates

Tags: sorting, knockout.js

I have the following view model:

```js
function instance(id, FirstName){
    $.extend(this, {
        id: ko.observable(id || ''),
        FirstName: ko.observable(FirstName || '')
    });
}
```

I have some instances in an observableArray:

```js
 ko.observableArray([new instance(...), new instance(...), ...]
```

With the following template:

```html
<ul data-bind='template: {name: "instanceTemplate", foreach: instances}'></ul>
```

And another template:

```html
<ul data-bind='template: {name: "anotherInsTmpl", foreach: instances}'></ul>
```

In first `ul` I need to render templates *without* sorting, in the second one render sorted by FirstName.

Can anyone explain how to do it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

One option would be to add a dependentObservable that represents the sorted array.  It would look something like:

```
viewModel.sortFunction = function(a, b) {
        return a.FirstName().toLowerCase() > b.FirstName().toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;  
};

viewModel.sortedInstances = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
    return this.instances.slice().sort(this.sortFunction);
}, viewModel);
```

So, do a case insensitive comparison of the value of the FirstName observable of each item.  Return a copy of the array (slice(0)) that is sorted (don't want to sort the real array).

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/93Z8N/

Note regarding Knockout Version 2.0 and greater: ko.dependentObservable is now ko.computed.  See [Dependent Observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/dependentObservables.html)

Comment: Tnx, RP Niemeyer. This is what I wanted:)